# icontains and SQL Security

Tags: python, django

I have a web app that allows users to enter a search query which will then retrieve models that match this search criteria. Here are my methods:

```
@staticmethod
def searchBody(query):
    '''
    Return all entries whose body text contains the query.
    '''
    return Entry.objects.get(text__icontains=query)

@staticmethod
def searchTitle(query):
    '''
    Return all entries whose title text contains the query.
    '''
    return Entry.objects.get(title__icontains=query)

@staticmethod
def searchAuthor(query):
    '''
    Return all entries whose author text contains the query.
    '''
    return Entry.objects.get(author.icontains=query)
```

My question is simply: is this secure as it stands? In other words, does `incontains` perform the necessary string escaping operations so a person can't inject SQL or Python code into the query to launch an attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Django ORM protects you against SQL injection.

Of course you can never be entirely sure that there is no security vulnerability in an application. Nevertheless, the ORM is the component responsible for protecting you against SQL injection, so you should assume it's safe and **keep your django install up to date**!

---

On an unrelated note, there is a typo in `Entry.objects.get(author.icontains=query)`.

Also, using `.get` is going to throw a lot of errors here (whenever the object doesn't exist, or more than one exist). It doesn't do what your docstring says either.

You probably want to be using `.filter` instead.

Comment: Also you can execute 
print Entry.objects.get(author__icontains='test').query and check what Django do with your parameter.